# Windows Phone ContactPicker won't await properly

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, asynchronous, async-await, contactpicker

Although this has been posted before on StackOverflow but i think none of those reflect my issue and none of those solutions work for me either. So i'm developing a Windows Phone app and my workflow is a bit like this:

- App starts
- ContactPicker opens up
- User selects one or multiple contacts
- Based on how many contacts he selected, that many PivotItems are added into the Pivot.

My code is as follows:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Prepare page for display here.

        // TODO: If your application contains multiple pages, ensure that you are
        // handling the hardware Back button by registering for the
        // Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed event.
        // If you are using the NavigationHelper provided by some templates,
        // this event is handled for you.

        SelectContacts();
    }

    private async Task SelectContacts()
    {
        var picker = new ContactPicker();
        picker.DesiredFieldsWithContactFieldType.Add(ContactFieldType.PhoneNumber);

        ContactsList = (List<Contact>)await picker.PickContactsAsync();
        DisplayContacts();
    }

    private void DisplayContacts()
    {
        if (ContactsList != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in ContactsList)
            {
                PivotItem pivotItem = new PivotItem();
                pivotItem.Header = item.FirstName.ToString();

                ContentRoot.Items.Add(pivotItem);
            }
        }
    }
```

According to me, in SelectContacts() method, the app should wait at the await call and once it gets back the list of contacts, than it should execute the DisplayContacts() method but its not working. I've tried multiple other variations of this code and they aren't working either.

Comment: what does "not working" mean?

Comment: @i3arnon it's not running in the correct order. Anything after await should be run once that line has completely executed but in my case it doesn't wait for the await line to completely execute.

Comment: What do you mean by "anything after the await". I assure you that `DisplayContacts` will only run after the awaited operation completed. Is there something else?

Comment: @i3arnon that is the exact problem. DisplayContacts runs before the await is completed. I know it shouldn't do that but it is.

Comment: I find that hard to believe. What happens if you call PickContactAsync().Result does it act the same?

Comment: @i3arnon Same result.

Comment: Then `PickContactsAsync` has definitively completed. Why do you think it shouldn't?

Comment: @i3arnon its not completed because i can see the contact picker on the screen and I've selected no contact.

Comment: maybe you found a bug in `PickContactsAsync` but there's no doubt await completed. What's stored in `ContactsList ` when it continues?

Comment: @i3arnon It shouldn't be a bug. Works in a older app of mine.
ContactsList is null when it continues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the complete reason why but i figured it out that since i was making the PickContactsAsync() call in the OnNavigatedTo() event, that is why it wasn't working as expected. Once i moved the PickContactsAsync() call into the PageLoaded() event handler, it started working as usual.

Answer (score 1):

await the SelectContacts() method and add the DisplayContacts() method beneath it.  Remove the DisplayContacts() method from SelectContacts()

```
await SelectContacts();
DisplayContacts();
```

Comment: Tried that as well. Doesn't work. I can still see the ContactPicker running on my emulator while DisplayContacts() doesn't wait for SelectContacts() and starts executing.

Comment: Try not casting the await as List<Contact>.  Instead, do something like

'var contacts = await picker.getContactsAsync();
if (contacts != null)
ContactsList = (List<Contact>)contacts;'